# Delete Event in Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the C# SDK to interact with facebook graph api in my asp.net mvc3 webapp

I used with success this code to add a event to my facebook account:

```
Dictionary<string, object> oParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
oParams.Add("name", e.Title);
oParams.Add("start_time", e.StartDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
oParams.Add("description", e.Synopsys);

dynamic result = _fb.Post("me/events", oParams);
```

and now I'm trying to make the oposite operation (Remove that event) but it does not work and returns the exception: "(GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported delete request."

This is the code I'm using to delete the event:

```
dynamic result = _fb.Delete("me/events/"+ e.FBID);
```

What is happening?

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using?